# Delete individual rows from database with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I get the values in the table from the database by `SELECT FROM...`(MySQL). This works fine, but now i want to have a delete button in each row that deletes this row from database. The problem is that the create dates all have the same name attribute

```
<?php  $createDate = $_REQUEST['createDate'] ;
```

function deleteQuantityPlan($createDate) {

```
createConnection();

$delete_quantity_plan = "DELETE FROM andon_quantity_plan where erstelldatum = '". $createdate ."'";

$result = mysql_query($delete_quantity_plan) or die ("error");

return;   }?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="shiftenter.php" method="post">
                <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color:#E1E1E1;width:65%;border-radius:10px;float:left;margin-left:17.5%;margin-right:17.5%;margin-top:2.5%">
                  <h3>Taktvorgabe hinzuf&uuml;gen!</h3>
                    <div style="height:5px;"></div>
                            <table style="font-size:12px;" id="tabelle" class="table">
                                <thead>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>Erstelldatum</th>
                                    <th>G&uuml;ltig von</th>
                                    <th>G&uuml;ltig bis</th>
                                    <th>Schichtnummer</th>
                                    <th>St&uuml;ck/min</th>
                                    <th style='float:right'>Taktvorgabe l&ouml;schen</th>
                                  </tr>
                                </thead>
                            <tbody id="table1Body">

                                <?php
                                $takttdaten = getAllQuantityPlans();

                                for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($takttdaten); $i++) {
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<form action='shiftenter.php' method='post'><td name='datum'>" . $takttdaten[$i]->erstelldatum . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $takttdaten[$i]->validfrom . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $takttdaten[$i]->validuntil . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $takttdaten[$i]->shiftnumber . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $takttdaten[$i]->planquantity . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td><button style='float:right;' class='btn btn-danger' type='submit'>X</button></td></form>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }
                                ?>
                         </tbody>
                     </table>
                </div>
            <button type="submit" style="width:15%;margin-top:35px;" class="btn btn-info">
                <span style="float: left;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>Taktvorgabe speichern!</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: I think for this case you should use AJAX. Send the id, recover it, delete the row.

Comment: then i have the problem that every row has the same id? Do i understand that right?

Comment: Hu ? Each row has its own id

Comment: if i write <tr id="test"> then every row has the id test, i think. Of course i could be wrong, I'm new in web developing

Comment: No, you should pass the MySQL id to your button or link, so that you can send it to the server call. Like `echo "<a href='javascript:send($takttdaten[$i]->id)' ...";`

Comment: like  echo "<a href='javascript:send($takttdaten[$i]->id)'><button name="deletePlan">x</button></a>

Comment: Actually you don't a button if you have a link. Or you can use a button instead of a link. Do you know how to use AJAX and event like onclick ?

Comment: I know the onclick event, but i didn't use ajax that much yet.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to 'DELETE', as opposed to 'hide from view'?

Comment: Yes it should be deleted in database thats the main thing, if it is deleted it won't be shown in the table because every time the page reloads the sleect query selects the whole table from database and loads it into this page,

Comment: So take a look at an ajax tutorial (consider using jquery for instance), and if you find trouble using that, feel free to ask.

Comment: I will thanks for answer, but is there no way to do it in PHP? I mean i dont need asynchronous queries because the page will be reloaded. i also write something in the database with php, so it have to be possible to delete something. I think its more useful than ajax in this case isn't it? :D

Comment: Of course you can do it with php only, just pass your id as a GET or POST parameter and then recover it, delete the row, and display the page. It's not user friendly, though

Comment: It doesn't have to be asynch. Of course you can do it with just PHP. Take a step back and forget about AJAX for a second. All you want to do is a) uniquely identify a row on your page by id. b) delete the corresponding record in the database for that id.

Comment: Now I have the problem that i cant have a form in a form^^ any solutions for that? For id: i also can do it like <td id="test++i" ></td> i think,  that the first td has test0 the second test1 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$delete_id = $_POST['checkbox'];` this code probably won't have a value. That's because your `checkbox` doesn't have a `value`. I think your code will work when you change:

`<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox'>`

Into

`<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value="<?= $takttdaten[$i]->[YOUR_ID_VARIABLE] ?>">`

**EDIT**

You can use just a link with GET variables instead of a form. Here's an example for your case:

Assuming the function in your comment/question is in the `shiftenter` file, change the PHP to :

```
if (isset($_GET['deletePlan']) && $_GET['deletePlan'] == 'true') {
    $deleteDate = $_GET['deletePlanDate'];

    if($deleteDate != null && $deleteDate != "")
    {
        deleteQuantityPlan($deleteDate);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Plan delete failed, Date [".$deletePlanDate."] was not valid.";
    }       
}
```

Then change the PHP section in your HTML table to:

```
<?php
$takttdaten = getAllQuantityPlans();
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($takttdaten); $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $takttdaten[$i]->erstelldatum . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $takttdaten[$i]->validfrom . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $takttdaten[$i]->validuntil . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $takttdaten[$i]->shiftnumber . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $takttdaten[$i]->planquantity . "</td>";
    echo "<td> <a href='shiftenter.php?deletePlan=true&deletePlanDate=".$takttdaten[$i]->erstelldatum ."'>Delete</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't, but thanks! Now i try it like: i give the create date as a parameter to the delete function, the delete function works but i have a form in a form an thats the problem now, and all rows have the same name for example "date", thats another problem because i give the name date to the function as parameter so the query isn't working now with 3 or 4 etc.. parameters

Comment: Hmm, yeah i understand. So what is your goal. Just delete one record right?

Comment: Yes, i just want to delete one row out of the database. As i sad the function works, but theres the name and form problem.

Comment: Yeah, but in your delete function you have a `foreach` loop. That's an indication that you try to achieve delete multiple rows right?

Comment: Oh sry for better understanding: I have a new function

i send the date as parameter with post/request to the function, now the problem is i cant send 3 parameters or 4 etc.. because they all have the same name attribute

Comment: Edited my question. Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Thanks i'll try that! :D hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From the code, I cannot see you are referencing the Id you want to delete.

This is your code:

```
echo "<td><form action='shiftenter.php' method='post'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox'>
<button style='float:right;' name='deletePlan' class='btn btn-danger' type='submit'>X</button></form></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

I would perhaps refactor your code.

In stead of having the a form element inside the last td, I would put the form around the whole table. 
You must then name the checkbox like this checkbox[] so it is defined as an array of checkboxes. You then get an array of checkboxes to loop over - those that has values that is (If I remember this correctly).

Based on the current code I have the following suggestions:

When you want to process this in PHP, you will do $_POST['checkbox'] in your shiftenter.php-file
But the checkbox does not have the number of your post in the database.
You can solve this by adding value to your input, or you could add a input type='hidden' name='itemid' value='[YOUR_ID_VARIABLE] ?>

This would then look something like this:

Solution 1: (which was suggested above)

```
echo "<td><form action='shiftenter.php' method='post'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='<?php echo $takttdaten[$i]->[YOUR_ID_VARIABLE] ?>'>
<button style='float:right;' name='deletePlan' class='btn btn-danger' type='submit'>X</button></form></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Solution 2:

```
echo "<td><form action='shiftenter.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='itemid' value='<?php echo $takttdaten[$i]->[YOUR_ID_VARIABLE] ?>'>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='<?php echo $takttdaten[$i]->[YOUR_ID_VARIABLE] ?>'>
<button style='float:right;' name='deletePlan' class='btn btn-danger' type='submit'>X</button></form></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

You then request this with $_POST['itemid'];

Alternative 3:

```
echo "<td><form action='shiftenter.php?itemid=<?php echo $takttdaten[$i]->[YOUR_ID_VARIABLE] ?>' method='post'>
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='<?php echo $takttdaten[$i]->[YOUR_ID_VARIABLE] ?>'>
<button style='float:right;' name='deletePlan' class='btn btn-danger' type='submit'>X</button></form></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

You can then get this value with $_GET['itemid'];

Do remember to check your values so they are ints (in this case). 
You can do this either like this:
$itemId = (int) $_POST['itemid'];
or using PHP sanitize filters which you can read about here: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Example of santizing here:

```
$myInt = "asfdsfsdafdsafs";
echo filter_var($myInt, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I tried it, also worked fine! :D but in my case i'd prefer first solution! Thank you! ;)